Why is the mesh getting messed up when I rotate the bone?
Why is the mesh getting messed up when I rotate the bone? I have subdivided and applied scale on the mesh. Please guide me on how to fix this.


you can solve this via shape keys: https://youtu.be/TSMARKpthhU?si=rr_yRugLargV7cEy

maybe segment the bones, also make sure that the Subdivision Surface is below the Armature modifier, or please share your file

I did not use subdivide modifier. I simply add loop cuts on mesh.

Please elaborate a little for us on what you mean by "messed up" so wee can best help you. I assume you do not like how the mesh is folding as you move the bone, in which case you may want to adjust the vertex weights of these bones to reduce how much they are affected by the rotation.

Using terminology "getting messed up" makes it feel you are not that familiar with how skinning / weights work. Image looks like a very typical result. Blender uses linear skinning, so you can think it like this: by default a vertex follows a bone 100%, think parenting a part of object into a bone. But when you weight a vertex into two bones, 50% for the first bone, and 50% to the second bone, you can imagine drawing a line between where vertex would be if moving 100% with either bone,  and this 50% weighted position is half way between the end points of this line.

Make sure all your normals are outbound.

See the bones as being parents of your vertices, with a factor between 0 and 1 (it's what you see in weight paint mode).
When you rotate a bone, it simply rotates the child vertices around it relative to their individual weight factor. So the deformation you see is expected:

Now if you want to correct that, we have different ways to deal with this:

Helper bones
corrective shape keys
topology tricks
Smooth Corrective Modifier

Or a combination of the above
